# Filter File, Moving values in file to list

Tags: python, python-2.7

my goal is to prompt the user for a file name, then find the given values inside of the file, move them to a list, and then find the average of those values. The values will always follow the same string. Currently I am simply trying to get the values into a list, or find an alternate method that may work better.

```
str1 = input("Enter file name:")
fhand = open(str1, 'r')
Valu_list = []
for line in fhand:
  line = line.rstrip()
  if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
    Valu_list.append = float(line[19:])
    break
  
  print(Valu_list)
```

the error im getting is AttributeError: 'list' object attribute 'append' is read-only.

I ask that you do not give me the entire program. I need more of a learning experience then outsource my work. If you can please help me better understand a way to get the values from file into list, or maybe making a list isn't the best option. I am still new to this so please be patient. Thank you for your time.

Comment: call append as a method `Valu_list.append(float(line[19:]))`

Comment: You are to assign a new value to the append method. To call the method use `Valu_list.append(float(line[19:]))`